# Microsoft Web Browser Automation for shopping cart?

Tags: c#, windows-services, automation, browser

I am doing a bit of research on how to automate the shopping cart checkout process programmatically.

Is this possible to do say running from a Windows service that runs on an interval?

So every X times a day the service will kickoff and order an item from a particular website. The checkout process will be examined thoroughly so all fields will be know and populated with data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of web automation tools available like Selenium, WatiN, or Coded UI.  You could also implement something directly by using the IWebBrowser2 interface to drive IE directly, if IE is the only browser you care about.  Selenium and WatiN abstract things out to make the automation simple and browser agnostic (assuming you're using a supported browser of course).